# Adding BATCH_TO_SPACE_ND and SPACE_TO_BATCH_ND to tensorflow lite

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, nnapi

NNAPI 1.1 already supported SPACE_TO_BATCH_ND and BATCH_TO_SPACE_ND ops but the current TFLite code isn't implemented yet. See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/nnapi_delegate.cc#L607

I tried to add them like this:

```
case tflite::BuiltinOperator_SPACE_TO_BATCH_ND:
   nn_op_type = ANEURALNETWORKS_SPACE_TO_BATCH_ND;
   break;
case tflite::BuiltinOperator_BATCH_TO_SPACE_ND:
   nn_op_type = ANEURALNETWORKS_BATCH_TO_SPACE_ND;
   break;
```

but it didn't work and there was an error message when I ran it on an android device: **E/Utils: Invalid number of input operands (3, expected 2) or output operands (1, expected 1) for operation BATCH_TO_SPACE_ND**

how can I add these ops to tensorflow lite properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer, to do this, you have to spend some time to understand their code architecture, then try to "translate" from tftensor to NNAPI:

for example: ANEURALNETWORKS_BATCH_TO_SPACE_ND (NNAPI) requires 2 params (input tensor, block_shape) while TFLite needs 3 args (input tensor, block_shape, crops), so you need to handle it to bypass errors.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer is correct. At the time NNAPI doesn't support crops so the code is only delegating operators [with zero crops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1a7cdfedc03322837282a274d464427f0bacec4e/tensorflow/lite/delegates/nnapi/nnapi_delegate.cc#L1849).

Comment: This does not answer the original question. If you found the other answer useful, you can vote it up. If you have any suggestions on the answer, you should leave a comment on that.